# NHibernate: Map one to many on unormalized table-structure

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a table which saves links to documents. The columns are like this:

link_id # table_name # table_id # link

The table_name column contains a reference to an other table and the table_id contains a reference to the PK of the other table.

This means, I have several tables which use this table to save links in a 1:n manner.

In NHibernate, I have several Business Entities which have nothing in common but that they store links in that table. Is there any way to map a One-To-Many relationship on such a table in each of these entities, so that these can contain a list of Links?`enter code here`

Comment: Are you using Castle ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing that resembles what you're looking for in the NHibernate world is the `<any>` mapping; you can read more about its usage in this [article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/21/nhibernate-mapping-ltanygt.aspx).